# Adding NGUniversal to my app stopped several things from functioning

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I added Angular Universal to my Angular 16 app and ran `npm run dev:ssr` just to discover several parts of my application aren't functioning.

1. None of my angular animations are working, as of right now I'm getting this error in my terminal

> @pageAnimation has failed due to:
> NG03014: `query(":enter, :leave")` returned zero elements. (Use `query(":enter, :leave", { optional: true })` if you wish to allow this.)

This particular animation is for the page transitions but I also have have a navbar at the top that slides down as the user scrolls along with a sidebar that slides in when the user clicks the hamburger menu in the top nav bar, neither of which work.

2. None of my `routerLink`s work anywhere on the site.  I can navigate to different pages by typing the path in the address bar but clicking the links has no effect whatsoever.
3. None of my buttons work in the application.  I created lots of control panels / dashboards with buttons that toggle different views with the `*ngIf` directive and none of them do anything.
4. I embed components into a resizable `<iframe>` component I built to demonstrate responsiveness.  None of those components embed into the .
5. I built a component that uses `highlight-js` to show code snippets on my site.  I store the snippets in a `string` variable on the parent component and pass them into the snippet component through an `@Input` which then passes it into the template.  All I see in my app are empty black boxes because the code snippets aren't being passed into the component for some reason.
6. I use the `ResizeObserver` API to watch the size of the `<iframe>` as the user scales it up and down.  The variables I store the new values to don't update as I scale the `<iframe>`.

I know these problems are occurring because certain browser objects aren't available on the server and have come across a few solutions people employed to resolve their issues however they haven't worked for me.  I tried injecting `PLATFORM_ID` into my `app.component.ts` file but that didn't make a difference.  I even imported the `afterRender()` method and ran it in my constructor however that doesn't seem to do anything either as I did a `console.log()` inside the callback I pass into it just to see if it was doing anything and nothing logged to the console.

I'm using all standalone components with no `app.module` file so I had to figure out on my own how to get everything setup to work however maybe I'm doing something wrong.  My files look like this:

***main.ts***

```
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter, withInMemoryScrolling } from '@angular/router';
import { SITEROUTES } from './app/routes';
import { HIGHLIGHT_OPTIONS, HighlightOptions } from 'ngx-highlightjs';
import { provideClientHydration } from '@angular/platform-browser';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideClientHydration(),
    provideRouter(SITEROUTES, withInMemoryScrolling({scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'})),
    provideAnimations(),
    {
      provide: HIGHLIGHT_OPTIONS,
      useValue: <HighlightOptions>{
        coreLibraryLoader: () => import('highlight.js/lib/core'),
        lineNumbersLoader: () => import('ngx-highlightjs/line-numbers'),
        languages: {
          xml: () => import('highlight.js/lib/languages/xml'),
          css: () => import('highlight.js/lib/languages/css')
        },
        themePath: '../node_modules/highlight.js/styles/a11y-dark.css'
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

***main.server.ts***

```
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { config } from './app/app.config.server';

const bootstrap = () => bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, config);

export default bootstrap;
```

***app.config.server.ts***

```
import { mergeApplicationConfig, ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideServerRendering } from '@angular/platform-server';
import {appConfig} from '../main';

const serverConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideServerRendering()
  ]
};

export const config = mergeApplicationConfig(appConfig, serverConfig);
```

***server.ts***

```
import 'zone.js/node';

import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { existsSync } from 'node:fs';
import { join } from 'node:path';
import bootstrap from './src/main.server';

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/srcry-documentation/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/main/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export default bootstrap;
```

***tsconfig.server.json***

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/server",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.server.ts",
    "server.ts"
  ]
}
```

Does anybody see what the problem is?  Am I missing something in one of these files?  Let me know if there's anything else you need to see and I'll update the post with the code.

Comment: Did you try the suggestion - `query(":enter, :leave", { optional: true })`? Did you load the `NoopAnimationsModule` in the app.server.module.ts

Comment: I don't have a `app.server.module.ts` file.  I don't have any modules as a matter of fact because the app is 100% standalone.  However I did try adding that code to my animation and tried importing both the `provideNoopAnimations()` and `provideAnimations()` methods to my `app.config.server.ts` file which makes the error go away but still doesn't make my animations work.

Comment: Okay, one step closer. I seem to remember that the `ngx-highlightjs` also does some kind of transition using the `requestAnimationFrame` browser javascript api, which fails during SSR. Perhaps it's coming from there, but i'd have to look into it too

Comment: ok I just tried adding all of the providers from my `main.ts` file to my `app.config.server.ts` file and I'm not getting an error saying `window is not defined` and it's pointing at the node module `@angular/animations/fesm2022/browser.mjs:4494:9`.  That chunk of code is `return window.getComputedStyle(element)[prop];`.  Now I installed a node package called `ssr-window` and use its `getWindow()` method in other parts of my application so I wonder if I should import it into this file to see if that would solve that problem.

Comment: I'm also getting an `element.animate is not a function` error too pointing at line `4359:24` of that same file.